# Order of Index Creation

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one clustered and several non-clustered indexes on a data warehouse table with about 18 M rows 170 columns - about 18GB in size.  The table comes from a Legacy system, and I cannot change it's structure.

This table is truncated and loaded on a daily basis.

For optimum performance, which is there an order to loading data and creating indexes?

Also, what do I do to this massive table in order to prep it for the indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Create the clustered index first since all non-clustered indexes will be based off of that one.

Comment: Do I Create the Clustered Index first or load the data first?

Comment: @RajMore Create the clustered index first, then load the data and finally create the non-clustered indexes.

Comment: Stefaneli What is the advantage of creating the clustered index first vs creating one after the data is loaded?

Comment: @RajMore Since the clustered index dictates the order of the physical data storage, it's better to have this in place ahead of time, rather than loading and then rearranging the data. The [BCP Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/mcp) even includes an `ORDER` hint that can improve its performance when the destination table has a clustered index.

Comment: I am loading this data using SSIS so I do not have the `BCP-ORDER` hint available.  How can I make this work using SSIS?

Comment: @RajMore My original advice is still valid. I was just using BCP as an example.